# PyQT slot calls seem to jump to the front of the event loop

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qt5, worker

I'm writing a GUI in PyQT to control some hardware. I've had a lot of problems with one particular instrument that I'm accessing through a company provided dll. It seems like something in the dll impacts the way Qt processes, but I don't understand how it works well.

In this case, I'm trying make a simple troubleshooting program that is periodically asking the equipment for its status based on a QTimer. I also have a button that runs an example "long process". I move these operations to a separate thread to not block the GUI. Something about this dll makes it such that I cannot connect to the equipment from multiple threads. I create this "Eqpt_Thread" and connect it to the main window. I find that the function connected to the timer can outpace itself occasionally. In the "NKT_System" class, I wrote an "is_busy" flag to try to block simultaneously operations from multiple threads (I also tried this using QMutex and has the same issues). I print out the status of the is_busy attribute going in and out of each method call within "NKT_System", and I find that the "long process" function is being called in the middle of the "get_eqpt_status" function execution (or vice versa). This causes a never-ending loop with my is_busy check since "long_process" is acting in the middle of "get_eqpt_status".

My issue is, "long_process" should be waiting for the currently running function "get_eqpt_status" to finish. This is operating on a single thread, as confirmed by the printed "QThread.currentThread()" lines. **How can "long_process" be interrupting execution of "get_eqpt_status" on a single thread?**

Note, I created a dummy program that replaces "get_eqpt_status" with `print(1); print(2)` and "long_process" with `print('a'); time.sleep(4); print('b')`, and I get the expected output 1, 2, a, b, 1, 2. When I'm using this equipment connection code, it's like I'm getting 1, 2, a, 1 - then everything crashes because of this unexpected behavior.

I've also tried not using Qt.QueuedConnection, though I figured that would help ensure I'm not overriding the EventLoop Queue when I click the button. Also I tried moving the QTimer that triggers get_eqpt_status into the Eqpt_Controller class, but that didn't give different results.

Also, there is some C++ example code provided with the DLL that shows use of the Qt class they use which gives me errors when multithreading. I see in the C++ example that they are creating local QEventLoop's. I wonder if that could be related, but I don't understand Qt or what is being provided in the DLL enough to know.

Code:

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QObject, Qt, QTimer, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QThread)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow,
                             QPushButton, QGridLayout, QWidget)

from catalight.equipment.light_sources import nkt_system


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """Subclass QMainWindow to customize your application's main window."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        print('Main window on:\t', QThread.currentThread())
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.widget = QWidget()  # Main widget

        # Create some widgets in GUI
        self.statusLabel1 = QLabel("Status Line 1:")
        self.statusLabel2 = QLabel("Status Line 2:")
        self.statusLabel3 = QLabel("Current Time:")
        self.statusLine1 = QLabel("-")
        self.statusLine2 = QLabel("-")
        self.statusLine3 = QLabel("-")
        self.manualCtrlBut = QPushButton("Start Long Process")
        
        # Place widgets in a layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.statusLabel1, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.statusLabel2, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.statusLabel3, 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.statusLine1, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.statusLine2, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.statusLine3, 2, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.manualCtrlBut, 3, 0, 1, 2)

        # Add layout to window
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        # Create dedicated equipment thread
        self.eqpt_thread = QThread()
        self.eqpt_controller = Eqpt_Controller()
        self.eqpt_controller.moveToThread(self.eqpt_thread)
        # Initialize Eqpt once new thread opens
        self.eqpt_thread.started.connect(self.eqpt_controller.connect_to_hardware)
        # Connect signals/slots
        self.eqpt_controller.eqpt_status_signal.connect(self.display_eqpt_status)
        self.manualCtrlBut.clicked.connect(self.eqpt_controller.long_process, Qt.QueuedConnection)
        # Start new thread
        self.eqpt_thread.start()
        
        # Create a timer and start it once hardware is initialized
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.display_time)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.eqpt_controller.get_eqpt_status, Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.eqpt_controller.eqpt_connection_finished.connect(lambda: self.timer.start(1000))

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot("PyQt_PyObject")
    def display_eqpt_status(self, eqpt_status):
        self.statusLine1.setText(str(eqpt_status['short setpoint']))
        self.statusLine2.setText(str(eqpt_status['long setpoint']))

    def display_time(self):
        # Get the current time in seconds since the epoch
        current_time_seconds = time.time()

        # Convert the time to a struct_time
        time_struct = time.localtime(current_time_seconds)

        # Format the time as HH:MM:SS AM/PM
        formatted_time = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", time_struct)

        # Print formatted time to GUI
        self.statusLine3.setText(formatted_time)


class Eqpt_Controller(QObject):
    eqpt_status_signal = pyqtSignal(dict)
    eqpt_connection_finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        print('Controller Init on:\t', QThread.currentThread())
       
    @pyqtSlot()
    def connect_to_hardware(self):
        print('run method is being called')
        print('Hardware Connection on:\t', QThread.currentThread())
        
        self.laser = nkt_system.NKT_System() # initilize hardware
        self.eqpt_connection_finished.emit() # notify GUI
        return

    @pyqtSlot()    
    def get_eqpt_status(self):
        print('Eqpt read on:\t', QThread.currentThread())
        
        # Read equipment status (These will print status)
        center = self.laser.central_wavelength
        bandwidth = self.laser.bandwidth
        
        # Compute values and save to dict, emit values to GUI
        short_setpoint = center - bandwidth/2
        long_setpoint = center + bandwidth/2
        eqpt_status = {'short setpoint': short_setpoint,
                       'long setpoint': long_setpoint}
        self.eqpt_status_signal.emit(eqpt_status)
        return
            
    @pyqtSlot()
    def long_process(self):
        
        print('Long process on:\t', QThread.currentThread())
        print('starting long process...')
        # This will print status for debugging
        self.laser.print_output()
        print('finished')
        return
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Main
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output of GUI after pressing button:

```
Loading x64 DLL from: C:\src\repos\nkt_tools\nkt_tools\NKTPDLL\x64\NKTPDLL.dll
Main window on:  <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x000002355C460820>
Controller Init on:      <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x000002355C460E50>
run method is being called
Hardware Connection on:  <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x000002355C460D30>
Searching for connected NKT Laser...
NKT Extreme/Fianium Found:
Comport:  COM8 Device type:  0x60 at address: 15
System Type =  SuperK Extreme
Inlet Temperature = 22.9 C
Searching for connected NKT Varia...
NKT Varia Found:
Comport:  COM8 Device type:  0x68 at address: 17
Last laser calibration was:
2023-12-20
Eqpt read on:    <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x000002355C460D30>
going into central wavelength    is_busy =  False
leaving central wavelength       is_busy =  False
going into bandwidth     is_busy =  False
leaving bandwidth        is_busy =  False
Long process on:         <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x000002355C460D30>
starting long process...
going into print output  is_busy =  False
Eqpt read on:    <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x000002355C460D30>
going into central wavelength    is_busy =  True
```

Notice how the last "going into central wavelength" line prints BEFORE the expected "finish" line from "long_process". This is causing my crashes

Comment: Isn't it simply the case that `self.laser.print_output()` operates asynchronously? It seems pretty clear that your application is anything but "single threaded". The mysterious dll you refer to very likely has no idea that it is being invoked by Python and/or Qt code, so there's nothing to stop it printing as and when it pleases. Does it use multiple threads and/or processes? If this a company provided dll, why can't you just ask the developers to explain how it works?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for your comment! I would think that it is not a matter of async behavior because the dll is being called by normal Python functions. laser.print_output() is my code that wraps the dll calls. The print statements are all my own. I would think that even if the underlying dll calls have some async aspect, the wrapping Python functions must behave sync if I haven't used async. If I have sync python functions A and B, funcA can call the dll and async can happen through the dll, but funcB shouldnt be able to "jump in" and call the dll since funcA needs to complete first, right?

Comment: Nope. The overlapping output you show is exactly as expected from code running multiple threads and/or processes. For one thing, you have a timer living in the main thread which communicates via signals with a worker object in a separate thread. In Qt, by default, cross-thread signals are handled asynchronously (i.e. they won't block event-processing in the sender, and *vice versa*). But note that this has got nothing to do with the Python-specific `async/await` (which I did not mention in my previous comment), so most of the statements in your comment aren't relevant.

Comment: However, there's no way to fully analyse your example, since you haven't provided a proper [mre] (i.e. no one else can test your code and try to reproduce the behaviour). Nevertheless, overlapping print output is very commonly seen in multithreaded code like yours, so there's no reason to suspect anything particularly unusual is going on. The only thing I can suggest is that you try calling `QApplication.processEvents()` in the worker slots and use `flush=True` when printing - but that's just guesswork, really.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks again for your feedback! I see what you mean, but I thought setting Qt.QueuedConnection would block my fast process (on timer) from cutting off the long_process?
ex:
@pyqtSlot()
    def fast_process(self):
        print('Eqpt read on:\t', QThread.currentThread())
        print(1)
        print(2)
        return

    @pyqtSlot()
    def long_process(self):

        print('Long process on:\t', QThread.currentThread())
        print('starting long process...')
        print('a')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print('b')
        print('finished')
        return

Comment: In the example in the above comment (which i'll try to reformat after) I do get the expected behavior. The code prints 1, 2, 1, 2, a ... b, 1, 2.

I've also tried putting the timer inside of the eqpt_controller thread so it is in the same parent thread as the functions I'm calling, but that didn't fix it. I'm not really sure how I can provide a minimal reproducible example, since this bug only comes when I'm communicating with a physical device. If I make my own dummy example, I the behavior I'd expect (1, 2, a, b, 1, 2)

Comment: If the "*bug only comes when I'm communicating with a physical device*", that would seem to prove the point of my initial comment. The code that invokes the dll functions seems effectively asynchronous - i.e. it doesn't block the local event-loop. Communication with the external device is probably IO-bound (as are the `print` calls), and thus not affected by the Python GIL. But again, this is mostly just guesswork, since your question is currently very light on the essential details and most of the critical code is missing.